# Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' when adding a registry

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Im developing a web application in c# and it uses entity framework to make a connection to a sql server database. Everything works fine but there is a weird problem when im trying to add an entity, the program throws an exception when the changes in the DB are been committed, so none of them can be saved.

This is the controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddEditEntidadFinanciera(AddEditEntidadFinancieraViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        using (var TransactionScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                TryUpdateModel(model);
                PostMessage(MessageType.Error, i18n.ValidationStrings.DatosIncorrectos);
                return View(model);
            }

            sgTabEntidadFinanciera EntidadFinanciera;
            sgTabReglaLimite regla;
            if (model.EntidadFinancieraId.HasValue)
            {
                EntidadFinanciera = context.sgTabEntidadFinanciera.Find(model.EntidadFinancieraId.Value);
                regla = context.sgTabReglaLimite.FirstOrDefault(x => x.fk_sgTabReglaLimite_sgTabEntidadFinanciera == EntidadFinanciera.PK_EntidadFinanciera);
                if (regla == null)
                {
                    regla = new sgTabReglaLimite();
                    regla.sgTabEntidadFinanciera = EntidadFinanciera;
                    context.sgTabReglaLimite.Add(regla);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                EntidadFinanciera = new sgTabEntidadFinanciera();
                regla = new sgTabReglaLimite();
                regla.sgTabEntidadFinanciera = EntidadFinanciera;
                EntidadFinanciera.fk_sgTabEntidadFinanciera_sgTabEstado = ConstantHelpers.ESTADO_SISTEMA_ENTIDAD_ACTIVO;
                context.sgTabEntidadFinanciera.Add(EntidadFinanciera);
                context.sgTabReglaLimite.Add(regla);
            }

            EntidadFinanciera.vRazonSocial = model.RazonSocial;
            EntidadFinanciera.vDireccion = model.Direccion;
            EntidadFinanciera.vRuc = model.Ruc;
            EntidadFinanciera.vAcronimo = model.Acronimo;

            EntidadFinanciera.fk_sgTabEntidadFinanciera_sgTabServidor = 1;
            EntidadFinanciera.vFtp = model.Ftp;

            EntidadFinanciera.vPasswordFtp = model.PasswordFtp;
            EntidadFinanciera.vRazonSocial = model.RazonSocial;

            EntidadFinanciera.vUsuarioFtp = model.UsuarioFtp;
            EntidadFinanciera.vVcBin = model.VcBin;
            EntidadFinanciera.vVcIPBancaDesarrollo = model.VcIPBancaDesarrollo;
            EntidadFinanciera.vVcMascaraCuentaExterna = model.VcMascaraCuentaExterna;
            EntidadFinanciera.vVcMascaraCuentaInterna = model.VcMascaraCuentaInterna;
            EntidadFinanciera.iLimite = model.Limite;

            if (model.Imagen != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Acronimo))
            {
                var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4) + Path.GetFileName(model.Imagen.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(ConstantHelpers.GetRutaImagenLogoEntidadFinanciera()), fileName);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(EntidadFinanciera.vRuta))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(EntidadFinanciera.vRuta));
                    model.Imagen.SaveAs(path);
                    EntidadFinanciera.vRuta = ConstantHelpers.GetRutaImagenLogoEntidadFinanciera() + fileName;
                }

            }

            //Here is when the exception is thrown  

            context.SaveChanges();
            TransactionScope.Complete();
            PostMessage(MessageType.Success);
            return RedirectToAction("LstEntidadFinanciera");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        ExceptionGlobokas exceptionGlobokas = new ExceptionGlobokas(ex.Message, log4net.Core.Level.Alert, ex);
        InvalidarContext();
        PostMessage(MessageType.Error);
        model.Fill(CargarDatosContext(), model.EntidadFinancieraId);
        TryUpdateModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

This is the output after the error message is shown
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqVjA.png)

I already checked that my PK has identity enabled in my database, also i verify if there is a problem with entity framework versions in App.config and Web.config, so im not sure what is causing the problem.

EDIT
Here is the InnerException message
[InnerExceptionImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fotGS.png)

And this is the Stacktrace

> at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>     at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>     at Globokas.SG.Controllers.AdminController.AddEditEntidadFinanciera(AddEditEntidad>FinancieraViewModel model) in D:\TFS_HL\Globokas.SG\Globokas.SG\Globokas.SG\Controllers\AdminController.cs:li>ne 2436

Comment: What is the message of InnerException property of your DbUpdateException?

Comment: You probably have a configuration issue. Can you post the resulting model and the mapping?

Comment: Posting stack trace & error details may helpful. I think DB update process has problem when saving database changes.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Sorry, im quite new with this, how do i check that?

Comment: @Miguel can you explain me what is the resulting model and the mapping please? Like i said above, im new in all of this

Comment: Yes, how is this class mapped to the database. Normally, this happens when you assign an entity (from outside of the context) with the Id that exists in the database, then when you attempt to SaveChanges the Context will try to create a new Entity with an existing Key.

Comment: @UrukGangsta there is a property named InnerException in exception details

Comment: @CodeNotFound Now i re-read my question and it sounds quite dumb xD, well i check the message of InnerException and it says there is a violation of the Primary Key because im trying to insert a duplicate, but it makes no sense because i already configurate the identity atribute on that column in my DB